# String encoding in javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, encoding, dropbox-api

I created a folder through the mac finder and named it `février` (french keyboard). I run a node.js script to return all the folders and files that are in this one. To get the name of the folders/files from the finder I used:

```
const files = fs.readdirSync(dir);

files.forEach((file) => {
  const path = `${dir}/${file}`;
  const stat = fs.statSync(path);

  if (stat && stat.isDirectory()) {
    results = results.concat(readLocalDir(path));
  } else {    
    results.push(path);
  }
});
```

It gives me an array with the full path `['février/image.png', ...]`.

Then I check with the dropbox api, if this file is already uploaded to my dropbox folder. I use the full path to check it with this:

```
return dropbox
  .filesListFolder({ path: `/${dir}`, recursive: true })
  .then(res => getFilesListContinue(res))

...

async function getFilesListContinue(res) {
  if (res.has_more) {
    const files = await dropbox.filesListFolderContinue({ cursor: res.cursor });

    return getFilesListContinue({
      has_more: files.has_more,
      entries: flatten([res.entries, files.entries]),
      cursor: files.cursor,
    });
  }

  return res;
}
```

Even though when I'm doing this, it returns that the file is not there, however, the folder and file are there, but the folder name has a different encoding.

I then checked the encoding of each folder name (the one on my finder, and the one on my dropbox). I used [detect-character-encoding](https://www.npmjs.com/package/detect-character-encoding) and this is what I got:

```
finder: février { encoding: 'ascii' }
dropbox: février { encoding: 'windows-1252' }
```

If you try to select the two `février` word through an editor, you will see you can't select the **same occurrence** as the first one, because they are not the same `février` =/= `février`.

Is there any simple way to convert my local ASCII(?) string to a `windows-1252` encoded string to be able to compare them against?

Comment: "février" *cannot* be expressed in ASCII. How are you checking the encoding?

Comment: Note that real ASCII doesn't have any letters-with-accents

Comment: You simply cannot do reliable automated encoding detection in a general basis. You should explain what actual problem you're facing (the way you describe it there doesn't seem to be any if you're getting `février` all the time).

Comment: @deceze I just edited my post!

Comment: Reading file system paths is tricky and it depends on the correct API to read paths correctly in the correct encoding. Likely Dropbox gets it right and what their API gives you is "correct", and whatever you're doing to read the local path is "wrong" in some way. It's also possible that neither gets it wrong, but that there's a difference in Unicode composition used and normalisation would fix that. Please just simply provide a clear code snippet that shows how you acquire both file names.

Comment: Thanks! That would make sense, I edited my post again

Comment: *"`février` =/= `février`"* – Well, as far as what we can see on Stack Overflow, they are identical… However, your sample above that probably hints at the real issue: OS X prefers the *decomposed* form ("e" followed by a combining accent) while Dropbox normalises that to the *composed* "é" character.

Comment: Yes I noticed it while editing the snippet code, the "é" is decomposed. Any way to prevent/fix/do something with that?

Comment: Put all your strings that you want to compare through the same Unicode normalisation. Not sure what the exact node.js API is for that, but light googling for this keyword should come up with something.

Comment: According to that nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_readdirsync_path_options, I changed the encoding used to read the directory to all the value possible, only `utf8`makes it possible to find the folder on the file system, even though it's still different as the one return by dropbox

Comment: Encoding and normalization are two different things.

Comment: @TomBlodget Thanks for the clarification, I got it now, I'll try in this way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As proposed in the comments, the solution is more simple that the problem can be complex. I just had to normalize the path return by `readdirSync` function

```
const files = fs.readdirSync(dir);

files.forEach((file) => {
  const path = `${dir}/${file.normalize('NFC')}`;
  ...
});
```

Comment: Had a problem trying to replace umlaut characters, but JavaScript couldn't find them. Using `normalize()` resolved this encoding problem.